# Report Server URL on SharePoint Integrated Mode

Tags: 2010, reporting-services

I have a SSRS 2008R2 integrated mode SharePoint 2010 environment and this environment is not working fine. So I want to reach the report server on that farm.

On native mode, `http://www.example.com/Reports/Pages/Folder.aspx` works fine. What can I do to reach reports on sharepoint integrated mode report server like the URL above?